# In angular should services always return this?

Tags: angularjs, service

Is it good practice or required to return the entire service via this? What if I omit it? All I have in one of my services is a simple function

```
angular.service('weatherService', function(){

var _this = this;

//default city
this.city = "New York, NY";
this.updateCity = function(string){
  _this.city = string;
}

});
```

vs

```
angular.service('weatherService', function(){

var _this = this;

//default city
this.city = "New York, NY";
this.updateCity = function(string){
  _this.city = string;
}

return this  <-------**is this required?**

});
```

Comment: Can you link the code of your service please? It's not very clear what you mean.

Comment: I have updated my example, sorry for not including code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Angular service works as an instance, so doesn't have to return anything. However factories must always return something. Please watch the difference between [services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) and [factories](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#factory-recipe):

#### Services

*Syntax*: `module.service( 'serviceName', function );`

*Result*: When declaring serviceName as an injectable argument you will be provided with an instance of the function. In other words `new FunctionYouPassedToService()`.

#### Factories

*Syntax*: `module.factory( 'factoryName', function );`

*Result*: When declaring factoryName as an injectable argument you will be provided with the value that is returned by invoking the function reference passed to module.factory. A factory can also return it's constructor.